# Laravel eloquent issue getting db datas

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I'm having a problem getting some datas from my database via eloquent:

at first I do this to get 'id' and 'capMax' from clase_schedule table:

```
$plazas = DB::table('clase_schedule')->select(['schedule_id', DB::raw('SUM(capMax) as capMax')])->groupBy('schedule_id')->get();
```

and then i want to get the the name of table schedule where the id i got before coincides with the one on this table, like this:

```
$nom_horarios = DB::table('schedule')->select('name')->where('id', 'in', $plazas->schedule_id)->get();
```

I get this error:

```
"Trying to get property of non-object"
```

Comment: what do you get on var_dump($plazas) ??

Comment: I get an array with two values, schedule_id and capMax that is the result of sum(capMax) for each group of values: array:2 [▼
  0 => {#483 ▼
    +"schedule_id": "2"
    +"capMax": "221"
  }
  1 => {#482 ▼
    +"schedule_id": "3"
    +"capMax": "12"
  }
]

Comment: if you are getting array then you should use loop to query again with the value in array .

Comment: doing the foreach i dont know why i just get the first one with this: foreach ($plazas as $plaza) { $nom_horarios = DB::table('schedule')->select('name')->where('id', 'in', $plaza->schedule_id)->get(); }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, `$plazas` is an array so you should loop the `$plazas` to get the value  in next query as below :

```
  foreach ($plazas as $plaza) 
    {
     $nom_horarios[] = DB::table('schedule')->select('name')->where('id', 'in',$plaza->schedule_id)->get(); 
    } 
    print_r($nom_horarios);
```

Comment: This one got the solution, i was missing the array sign in $nom_horarios
thnks

Comment: Great !! If you find this answer helpful then please tick it so that it can be useful to others in future ::) .

Answer (score 0):

$plazas returns an array of items, instead of get(), use first(). This will return single item.

```
$plazas = DB::table('clase_schedule')->select(['schedule_id', DB::raw('SUM(capMax) as capMax')])->groupBy('schedule_id')->first();
```

Or loop plazas in foreach

Comment: the thing is that what i want to get is the name of each of the items in the array

Comment: doing the foreach i dont know why i just get the first one with this: 
foreach ($plazas as $plaza) {
            $nom_horarios = DB::table('schedule')->select('name')->where('id', 'in', $plaza->schedule_id)->get();
        }

Comment: do  var_dump($plazas->count()); ans see how many plazas you're returning

Comment: im getting two items on the array

Answer (score 0):

What is returning in the `$plazas` variable?

I think the problem is you are getting a collection and not a item... If you want to get just one plaza you should `->first()` instead of `->get()`;

Comment: I get an array with two values, schedule_id and capMax that is the result of sum(capMax) for each group of values: array:2 [▼ 0 => {#483 ▼ +"schedule_id": "2" +"capMax": "221" } 1 => {#482 ▼ +"schedule_id": "3" +"capMax": "12" } ] 
What i want to get is the name of each id in table schedule

Comment: You can do $plazas->only('schedule_id'), that way you'll get just the ids, then call the in operator. Like this **$nom_horarios = DB::table('schedule')->select('name')->where('id', 'in', $plazas->only('schedule_id'))->get();**

Comment: Sorry, the only will get in separetad arrays still.. The map function can fix $this **$plazas->map(function($obj){return $obj->schedule_id;});**